# How to remove extra header from excel export from GI

Tags: acumatica

When I export GI data to excel, it does export some header info such as GI name, filter, etc. Where as if I export any data from grid such as SO Line items, it does not export any header info. Does anyone has any idea how can I get rid of those extra header info when I export it to excel from GI. Or it would have been better if there is any option (check/uncheck) whether one needs these header or not while export GI data.

Answer (score 1):

No option is available to export GI to Excel without header because of the DashboardType attribute decorating PXGenericInqGrph class (PXGenericInqGrph is used to open every GI in the application):

```
[DashboardType(PXGenericInqGrph.DASHBOARD_TYPE, PXGenericInqGrph.DASHBOARD_CHART_TYPE)]
public partial class PXGenericInqGrph : PXGraph<PXGenericInqGrph>
{
    ...
}
```

As a workaround you can create a custom inquiry screen, that will not have DashboardTypeAttribute.

For additional information, you might also check [Can I add a custom header to exported Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617033/can-i-add-a-custom-header-to-exported-excel-file) thread